# Calculate infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to find a closed for the following sum:

$\sum_{i=1}^\infty a^{i^\beta}$

Where $|a|<1$, and $\beta\geq 1$. Anyone any ideas?

Best,

Ben

Comment: See the [theta functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function) for $\beta = 2$.

Comment: I'm looking for an inswer when $\beta=3$ but without success

Comment: I doubt one exists, but I wouldn't be too surprised if one were to be found.